# OLS assumptions for weighted errors

Tags: regression, least-squares, normality-assumption, assumptions, weights

As far as I know, under satisfied assumptions for OLS, the estimates acquire qualities like BLUE, MVUE, MLE.

But in the case where there is a priori knowledge of the influence of each data point, it is not obvious a weighted errors or just a errors should satisfy assumptions, particularly homoscedasticity and normality.

Regardless of the answer, please be kind to prove your point in simple language (for example, for someone who has just graduated from school or a little more).